# I have viewcontrollers in a scrollview, but how do I start on a certain page?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a scroll view with 3 viewcontrollers which scrolls horizontally, one of the viewcontrollers has 3 more viewcontrollers which scroll vertically. The only way to access these viewcontrollers is by logging in. On the vertical scrollview I want the middle page to be the starting page, then the user has the option to scroll up or down. Right now the vertical scrollview starts with the first page, but I want it to start with middle page (second page).

```
 @IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let profile: ProfileView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profile") as! ProfileView
    let music: View2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as! View2
    let camera: Camera = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("camera") as! Camera

    self.addChildViewController(profile)
    self.scroller.addSubview(profile.view)
    profile.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(music)
    self.scroller.addSubview(music.view)
    music.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(camera)
    self.scroller.addSubview(camera.view)
    camera.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var musicFrame: CGRect = profile.view.frame
    musicFrame.origin.y = 2 * self.view.frame.height
    music.view.frame = musicFrame

    var profileFrame: CGRect = camera.view.frame
    profileFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
    profile.view.frame = profileFrame

    self.scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height*3)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: You should use UITableView instead of UIScrollView to hold those view controllers. It's easier to scroll exactly with table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollview has a contentoffset which you can set the y position of. Detect the the y position of the middle view and set the scrollviews contentOffSet to it

If memory serves you'll have to animate (or not) the change to the contentOffset in viewWillAppear